# how redis ensure all request data can be readed into buffer by only one 'read' function call?

Tags: redis

I read redis source code recently, and I'm now studying the networking codes.

Redis use nonblock mode and epoll(or something simliar) for networking data read/write. When read data event arrived,"readQueryFromClient" function will be called, and in this function request data will be readed into buffer.

In "readQueryFromClient" function, if there are really data arrived, data will be readed into buffer through one 'read' function, and then the request will be handled.

```
 nread = read(fd, c->querybuf+qblen, readlen); // **one read function**
//... some other codes to check read function retuen value
processInputBuffer(c);// **request will be handled in this function**
```

My question is: how redis ensure all request data can be readed into buffer by only one 'read' function call, maybe all data will be gotten by more 'read' function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> processInputBuffer(c);// **request will be handled in this function**

That part is not true. Redis protocol is designed to include length of every chunk of data passed around. So the server always knows how much data it has to read to make a complete request out of it. Inside `processInputBuffer` if neither `processInlineBuffer` nor `processMultibulkBuffer` returns `REDIS_OK` (i.e. request terminator was not found in the buffer/not enough arguments), control simply falls out of the function. All that `processInputBuffer` did in this case was filling up a chunk of the client buffer and updating the parsing state. Then, on the next iteration of event loop, in the call to `aeProcessEvents`, if there is unread data remaining in the socket buffer, `readQueryFromClient` callback will be triggered again to parse the remaining data.